# Assert schema of javascript object on function callback handler

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, callback

I have an object with structure like this: `{prop_1: function_1, prop_n: function_n}`. I use jest to unit-test my code, which you may check here: https://jestjs.io.

Functions provided by `prop_${i}` have some requirement object `{prop_1:requirementCallback_1, prop_n: requirementCallback_n}` needed such that `requirementCallback_${i}`, for example, that given function returns a defined value or it asserts some expected number of input arguments. Therefore, it is advisable from my point of view that we run requirement values against `function_{i}` to verify such conditions.

I am not familiar to Typescript, but its name suggests that the language may have some out-of-the-box solution to check such conditions. What do you think about this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Does the object have dynamic properties? then try:

```ts
//change void to your appropriate return type
type MyObjectType = Record<string, (someStringArg: string, someNumberArg: number) => void >
```

If you are trying to have defined properties with same funtion types then try:

```ts
type SameFunctionType = (string_arg1: string, number_arg2: number)=>void//or any return type for the function
interface MyObjectType{
  prop_1: SameFunctionType;
  prop_n: SameFunctionType;
}
```

If you are trying to have defined properties with different funtion types then try:

```ts
interface MyObjectType{
  prop_1: ()=>number;
  prop_2: (arg1: Date)=>number;
}
```

Comment: I try to sketch a jest-based supportive library for unit-testing. Take a look: https://github.com/quivero/prego/tree/feat-refac-atest-workflow/utils/testing . In this context, there is always an object with schema `{"setup": () => {}, "prepare":  (x) => x, "teardown":   () => {}}`.  The provided values are default in case of not given. I currently work on it by branch `feat-refac-atest-workflow`